# Как доработать скрипт Loadmore?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как доработать скрипт, чтобы кнопка LoadMore была скрыта, если 4 записей по умолчанию. А то получается кнопка LoadMore отображается, даже если записей меньше четырех

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: Добавить проверку, что записей больше 4х. У вас, в редоставленном скрипте нет никаких проверок...

Comment: А вы не подскажете как добавить проверку?

Comment: Так у вас не ясно, что значит записей 4 по умолчанию??? где эти записи? Что бы проверить пишите `if (количество записей <= 4) скрыть else показать`. Вы же даже не указали как вы скрываете или отображаете кнопку... [Условные операторы javaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)